# How to test controller and search parameters in rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

I'm new in Rails, previously I've tested in RSpec.
I have the next controller in Rails 6 app:

```
  def index
    @query = params[:query]
    search_params = if @query.present?
                      { name_cont: @query, knowledges_description_cont: @query, m: 'or' }
                    else
                      params[:filter] || {}
                    end
    @q = Course.active.ransack(search_params)
    @courses = @q.result(distinct: true).includes(:programs).order(name: :asc).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
  end

  def show
    @course = Course.active.includes(:knowledges, :requirements, :programs).find_by!(slug: params[:id]).decorate
  end

  def cashback
    course = Course.find_by!(slug: params[:id])
    redirect_to(course.site.cashback? ? course.site.cashback_url : course.site_url)
  end

  def go
    course = Course.find_by!(slug: params[:id])
    redirect_to(course.active? && course.site.active? ? [course.site.deeplink_url, course.site_url].join : course.site_url)
  end
end
```

And also the net factory for it:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :course do
    site
    name { 'test' }
    description { 'description' }
    short_description { 'short_description' }
    site_url { 'www.example.com' }
    slug { 'sth-course' }
    level { Course::LEVELS.sample }
    meta_title { 'meta-title' }
    meta_description { 'meta-description' }
    meta_keywords { 'keyword' }
    price { 1000 }

    trait :deleted do
      state { 'deleted' }
    end

    factory :deleted_course, traits: [:deleted]
  end
end
```

I've never use slag before. How should I write test here?
I think, I should check some parameters in query and assert, if it finds something, but I don't know how to do it. Also, should I make new test object in `setup` constructor, or I should use factory for it?

Comment: You test controllers with [integration tests](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing) which sends HTTP requests to your application and you then write assertions about the response. Get that figured out first (hint there are tons of articles). Slugs don't really effect the process that much. You just pass a slug instead of an ID to the route.

Comment: When it comes to that index route its going to be a royal PITA to test since there is so much going on. Create an object that takes a scope (`Course.all`) and a hash of parameters and applies the search filters. This lets you test the object directly by passing in input and write assertions directly about the return value. Call it service object or whatever you want. Just get the logic somewhere where you can test it in a straight forward way.